# MongoDB $pull efficiency

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, time-complexity

Let's assume following schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: { type: [Number] }
});
schema.index({ _id: 1, data: 1 });
var model = mongoose.model('Test', schema);
```

How efficient is `$pull` operator when removing entries from `doc.data`?

```
model.update({ _id: someId }, { $pull: { data: { $lte: 123 } } }).exec();
```

Will it use the index and run in O(log n + m) complexity, where n is the number of elements in data and m the number of removed elements? Or does it have to scan whole array?

And what's the complexity of removing an element after Mongo finds it? Is it O(1), O(log n) or O(n) as it has to shift other items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection's indexes are only used for the doc finding part of the update, not the update itself.

So the built-in index on `_id` will be used to find the document, but the `$pull` update will require the whole `data` array be read and scanned against the `{$lte: 123}` query: O(n).

The index you added on `{ _id: 1, data: 1 }` would only be used if you also included `data` in your actual query as:

```javascript
model.update({_id: someId, data: {$lte: 123}}, {$pull: {data: {$lte: 123}}}).exec();
```

But that would only provide a benefit in the case where `data` contained *no* elements with a value <= 123 by short-circuiting the update as the doc would no longer match the criteria. It still wouldn't be used to find the `data` elements for the `$pull` itself.